# Two foreign keys referencing same column

Tags: mysql

I have two Tables : Livestream and Team.

**Livestream:**

```
id_livestream int primary key

id_team1 int

id_team2 int
```

// I had already referenced these two columns to Team id_team column

**Team:**

```
id_team int primary key

name_team varchar(40)

image_team varchar(255)
```

I want to select name_team from Team for both referenced columns in Livestream..
as example i want to show something like:

id_team1| name of team1| image of team1 | id_team2| name of team 2| image of team2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate the output you want by simply doing two joins from the `Livestream` table to the `Team` table:

```
SELECT
    lm.id_team1,
    t1.name_team AS name_team_1,
    t1.image_team AS image_team_1,
    lm.id_team2,
    t2.name_team AS name_team_2,
    t2.image_team AS image_team_2
FROM Livestream lm
INNER JOIN Team t1
    ON lm.id_team1 = t1.id_team
INNER JOIN Team t2
    ON lm.id_team2 = t2.id_team
```

I assume here that every team appearing in `Livestream` will have an entry somewhere in the `Team` table.  If this be not the case, and you don't want `NULL` values appearing in your result set, then you can switch to using a `LEFT JOIN` along with `COALESCE()`.

Comment: I did that i have to wait 10minutes to re mark a correct answer :)
But sorry i want ask something more :

let s  suppose i have a child table named Livestream_details referencing Livestream

I want if i delete a row in Livestream automatically to delete its reference from Livestream_details

Where should i use on delete cascade ?

Comment: This sounds like a totally different question, such that I wouldn't answer it here in the comments section.  You might want to ask a new question, but `ON DELETE CASCADE` sounds like an option.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    ls.id_team1,
    t1.name_team AS name_team_1,
    t1.image_team AS image_team_1,
    ls.id_team2,
    t2.name_team AS name_team_2,
    t2.image_team AS image_team_2
FROM Livestream ls
INNER JOIN Team t1
    ON ls.id_team1 = t1.id_team
INNER JOIN Team t2
    ON ls.id_team2 = t2.id_team
```

Inner join two times with `Team` does the trick.